# Help understanding the difference between "to have+verb" and "to+verb"

Tags: infinitives, perfect-constructions

I'm always confused about using 'to have'. I know it is a perfect infinitive but the meaning of it must have a different usage than 'to+verb'!

> If you go there you need **to have registered** a room.

Why it is not just "to" before register?

> It would've been possible **to have met** him if you'd been there.
>
> To appreciate the success, you need **to have had** the failure.

Why not just "to have" instead of "to have had"?

Comment: The second example is weird, because the double use of past tense implies, to me, although I can't point you at a rule, the past before the past. I read it as *to have had met* instead of just *to have met*. And the sentece is complicated by use of the self-referential *it*, which refers to the sentence itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you go to a very popular restaurant where it is difficult to get a seat, and you must make a reservation weeks in advance.

> To eat there, you have to make a reservation.

Now, let's say a tourist is visiting the city, and does not know that the restaurant is always full. He enters, expecting to be seated.  The greeter can say:

> Sorry, you **have to make** a reservation *beforehand*.

or

> Sorry, you **have to have made** a reservation.

The first version, "have to make", describes the general state of affairs. People who wish to eat there must reserve a place in advance. This is probably what the greeter would say, or even "You **need** a reservation". Present tense, to describe what is *customary*.

The second version describes the very specific situation in respect to *time*. The person is standing now in the restaurant. The person should have made a reservation already, in the past: When you come here, expecting to be seated, you must **have made** a reservation.

The tense **have made** contains the idea "beforehand", that is, "before now". The reservation should exist *already*.

Comment: The first version is some form of paste tense because of the temporal aspect of beforehand.

Comment: No, @Hector von, the first version is in present tense, not past tense. **have to make** = "are obliged to make". You have to make a reservation is in the present tense. **beforehand** simply means "earlier than {the thing in question}". You can even use it with the future: *When you visit London next year, be sure to arrange lodgings beforehand.*

Comment: And "earlier than" pretty much means past tense in relation to the predicate of "beforehand", which admittedly comes down to the present tense if the predicate is in the future tense: "You have to make a reservation before you will come here". But that is often rendered, "next time, before you come here" where the "next time is enough to signal future. Correctly though "next time" requires future tense, before you will come here". That's analytic versus syntactic language.

Comment: **beforehand** is relative and refers to a sequence of events, and those events can be situated in the past, present, future, or even in the hypothetical realm.  As I said, and showed with the London lodgings example, you can use it with the future.  We can leave out "next year" or leave it in.

Comment: sorry, edited because I hit enter too soon

Comment: Also relevant to the question is lexical aspect, as [I discussed here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122458/does-to-refer-to-a-future-event/122462#122462).

Comment: If I simply say, you need to have made a reservation. Then what is the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: "To have made" explicitly indicates that you should have made the reservation  *already*.

Comment: I am a little confused,  Is this sentence refer the same meaning below.                                                                                To appreciate the success, you need to have had the failure.

Comment: **have had** conveys the meaning *already*. To appreciate success on a particular effort, you must have already tried to do it, and failed in your attempt. Compare that to *To appreciate success, you must fail*.  Nowhere there does it say "fail *beforehand*". We supply the idea, that first comes the failure and then comes the success. But it could just as easily be understood to mean: "You don't appreciate your early success until later on you fail at something else". **have had** makes clear the order of the events: to appreciate success, you must have experienced an *earlier* failure.

Comment: And one more question arises in my mind is that, is there any difference between both the sentences below? you have to have made a reservation. &. You need to have made a reservation

Comment: If the entire sentence itself is in the past then what is the role of 'to have' in the sentence below.                                                         it would've been possible to have met him if you'd been there,

Comment: I don't follow your question. **to have made** is a perfect infinitive. The  infinitive is required when "have" means "must".  You have *to make* ....You have *to have made*.