# Present Simple vs Future Simple vs Present Continuous vs "Going to" vs Future Obligation for events in near future

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, present-continuous, present-simple, will-vs-going-to

Grammar tells us that Present Simple, Future Simple, Present Continuous, Future obligation, and "Going to" can all speak about the events that take place in the future. But for near future events what is better to use and what is correct?

- The shop opens at 8am tomorrow morning.
- The shop will open at 8am tomorrow morning.
- The shop is opening at 8am tomorrow morning.
- The shop is going to open at 8am tomorrow morning.
- The shop is to open at 8am tomorrow morning.

What about Present Continuous, Future obligation, and "Going to"? Can we use them for objects and things? I've known so far that this is wrong.

- The bus is leaving in ten minutes. **(Wrong)**
- The bus is going to leave in ten minutes. **(Wrong)**
- The bus is to leave in ten minutes. **(Wrong)**
- The bus leaves in ten minutes. **(Correct)**
- The bus will leave in ten minutes. **(Correct)**

**Edit**. A few more sentences add to the list:

- The bus shall leave in ten minutes.
- The bus should leave in ten minutes.

Comment: Actually, none of those sound wrong to me.  Some are more common than others, but all of them are grammatically correct and understandable.  Particularly **the bus is leaving in ten minutes** - that sounds perfectly natural, like something I would say myself.

Comment: @stangdon I read Michael Swan's grammar books and as far as I remember it was written there that "going to", Future Obligation and Present Continuous about the Future can't be used with objects. We can't say "The plane is taking off in 20 minutes" but we can say "I am coming out in 5 minutes"

Comment: This is from British Council *"We can use the present continuous to talk about arrangements (plans which you have organised) in the future"* A plane cannot make arrangements or plan anything and neither can the bus nor the shop.

Comment: @SovereignSun, In that sense, the plane or the bus could be understood as metaphors ([metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)). By the same line of argument, I assume, you could reason, the bus lacks will.

Comment: If you talk about obligation, I would add "should leave/open" to the list. Otherwise you answered your question already. I'm just not quite sure about the correctness of of the continuous forms ... thinking about it, in the chosen examples they are most fit, because you talk about a repeated action, only the time frame is a matter of interpretation then, e.g. "in ten minutes (every day at that time)".

Comment: Another variant to highlight the [aspect of achievement](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122458/does-to-refer-to-a-future-event) combined with recurrence: "is to be leaving"

Comment: I'm not sure in which book and under which entries Swan says *The bus is leaving in ten minutes* is incorrect. (I have *Practical English Usage*, and I can't find him saying that in the book.) -- It might be better if we see exactly what Swan says.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm not sure, but anywhere I look I see it used only with personal pronouns. I hope somebody explains.

Comment: @SovereignSun Maybe it's because you use the full form *is/are going to*. Try it with the 's and you may find more results. (I just did a quick search for *"this country's going to be"*, and found many results.)

Comment: The only sentence I would not say in normal conversation (but would readily write in a legal contract) is "The bus shall leave...".  That's my downvote, for "misinformation".  **is to** is quasi-modal, synonymous with "must".  It isn't a future indicative.

Comment: @SovereignSun - regarding *"We can use the present continuous to talk about arrangements (plans)"*, I think you're reading it a little too literally.  There is certainly an arrangement or plan that the bus will leave in ten minutes; it doesn't have to literally mean that the bus is making the plans.

Answer (score 3):

Future indicative:

> The bus **is leaving** in ten minutes. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> The bus **is going to leave** in ten minutes.  <sup>grammatical</sup>

If things go as usual or if things are to go well:

> The bus **should leave** in ten minutes <sup>it usually leaves then</sup>.
>
> The bus **should leave** in ten minutes. <sup>or it will be late</sup>

Requirement:

> The bus **is to leave** in ten minutes. <sup>This bus *must* leave in 10
>   minutes</sup>
>
> The bus **shall leave** in ten minutes. <sup>ditto†</sup>
>
> The contract states that "Supplier **shall deliver** the merchandise not
>   later than the 15th day of each month" and that "Customer may
>   terminate this agreement early without penalty should Supplier ever fail to make a
>   timely delivery."

†Some speakers use **shall** as well with future indicative. That is exceedingly rare in AmE.

Comment: What about the other variants? And how about the *"The bus leaves in 10 minutes"*?

Comment: Is that your downvote?

Comment: Yes. And this answer doesn't exactly help me. Why are the first two grammatical?

Comment: I'm addressing only the inaccuracies in your question. Give reasons for your downvotes.

Comment: They're grammatical because they're grammatical. Your question reveals a deep ignorance of the nature of grammar.